# Noisy feather selections in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Whenever I put some kind of feather on selection. Or there is some angled selection; there is a noisy type of selection. How to get rid of it? Refer to the link for image please.

[image]

Comment: are you making the selection on a separate layer? this appearance is generally caused by the 'dissolve' layer style instead of the 'normal' layer style

Answer (score 1):

Given that in your screenshot, you only have the `Background` layer, I believe that you tried to delete the selection or simply used `Edit > Fill` ( Same thing in this case ).

You must have had the Fill blending mode as `Dissolve`, which is causing it to come out like this. The selection is feathered normally, it's just your fill that comes out looking grainy. You'll probably want to use blending mode `Normal`.

[image]

---

This is not the only place where this can go wrong. Some of the tools have their own blend mode too. `Paint bucket tool`, for instance.  Each layer has their own blend mode setting as well.

Comment: `Pro tip: ` I never use the feather option. **1.** I make the selection. **2.** Then turn `Quick mask` on with `(Q)` **3.** Apply blur with `Filter > Blur > Gaussian blur...`. **4.** Turn `Quick mask` off with `(Q)`  ---- I like this, because I can see exactly what the "feathering" looks like, so I don't have to be guessing.

Comment: Protip: Never say never.... The above comment just isn't always practical. Say budget retouching jobs where you need to do some smoothing without spending hours.

Comment: @Ryan I'd say I'm spending less time with this method, because I know the amount of feathering I'm getting, rather than guessing, trying it and guessing again. t has more steps, but it isn't much slower. If speed is a concern, you could make an Action out of that workflow. I 100% stand behind that comment and will continue to say no to the feather option.

Comment: Although, I'd like to see you try and convince me how the feather option is faster and more practical.

Comment: making a video real fast for you to try and prove my point

Comment: Come on in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36840/feather-or-never-feather